# dirname('/test') == '\\'?

Tags: php

```
echo dirname('/test');
```

That outputs \ for me. I'd expect it to output /.

```
echo dirname('/test/a');
```

That outputs /test for me so why isn't /test giving me / as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this from http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

```
<?php
echo "1) " . dirname("/etc/passwd") . PHP_EOL; // 1) /etc
echo "2) " . dirname("/etc/") . PHP_EOL; // 2) / (or \ on Windows)
echo "3) " . dirname("."); // 3) .
?>
```

Since windows uses both `/` and `\` as directory separator, this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) on php.net.

There are some pretty nice examples there.